# regular expression not matching, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make a replacement between a string containing a link, with the same string encapsulated in html href blocks. I'm new to regular expressions and have been reading up on them - I've come up with this expression going through SO and other sites.

```
$s = 'This is a stupid site: www.etsy.com';
$regEx = '#(^www\.|^http://)([a-zA-Z0-9/?\-&=_\.]+\.com|\.net|\.org|\.ca)|(/[a-zA-Z0-9/?\-_&=\.]+)#';
$ret = preg_replace( $regEx, "<a href='$1$2$3'>$1$2$3</a>", $s);
echo $ret;
```

This doesn't return me a link at all

and this doesn't include "http://" in the link:

```
$s = 'This is a stupid video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkXVM6ad9nI';
$regEx = '#(^www\.|^http://)([a-zA-Z0-9/?\-&=_\.]+\.com|\.net|\.org|\.ca)|(/[a-zA-Z0-9/?\-_&=\.]+)#';
$ret = preg_replace( $regEx, "<a href='$1$2$3'>$1$2$3</a>", $s);
echo $ret;
```

I'm still trying so this might change... but any help would be appreciated as I'm nearing my wits end.

Thank you in advance for your time

P.S: I tried this in RegexBuddy and the whole string gets highlighted when I test... so I'm really wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `^` anchors the start of a line or the whole string subject.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is that you are trying to parse HTML with regular expressions, which is impossible, since HTML is not a regular language. Use a HTML parser instead.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: He's trying to parse a URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @BobBrown and HTML. Look at the `preg_replace()` line.

Comment: I haven't dug deep enough to find the answer, but the `#` is an X-mode comment.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant:  He's parsing a URL to build HTML.  That ought to work.

Comment: Give up on the regular expression.  Break this into two parts: Find a URL within a string, then use PHP's `parse_url` function to parse the URL.

Comment: @mario - thank you, that actually fixed it. I do get my links now with this regular expression changed to not have the ^.

Comment: @Bob Brown, thank you as well - I'll be implementing a different solution using parse_url

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$s = 'This is a stupid site: www.etsy.com';
$regEx = '#(www\.|http://)([a-zA-Z0-9\/?\-&=_\.]+\.com|\.net|\.org|\.ca)(/[a-zA-Z0-9/?\-_&=\.]*)?#';
$ret = preg_replace( $regEx, "<a href='$1$2$3'>$1$2$3</a>", $s);
echo $ret;
```

[And test HERE](http://regex101.com/r/fK7nT5/2)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches, for example:

```
www.whatever.com
```

or

```
www.net
```

but not

```
www.whatever.net
```

You have to group the TLDs:

```
$regEx = '#(^www\.|^http://)([a-zA-Z0-9/?\-&=_\.]+(\.com|\.net|\.org|\.ca))|(/[a-zA-Z0-9/?\-_&=\.]+)#';
//                                         here __^   and         here  __^
```

You could also simplify it:

```
$regEx = '#^((?:www\.|http://)[\w/.-]+\.(?:com|net|org|ca))#';
$ret = preg_replace( $regEx, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>", $s);
```

Where:

`(?:...)` is a non capture group.
`\w` stands for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`